# What is the branch of mathematics called that deals with differential equations over finite fields?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, finite-fields, cyclic-groups

What is the branch of mathematics called that deals with differential equations over finite fields? For example, Laplace's equation
$$
\nabla^2 \phi = 0
$$
is usually defined for a scalar field $\phi$ that spans real or complex numbers. Is there an analogue equation for $\phi$ defined over a set of cyclic numbers, say, between $0$ and $2\pi$, or a Galois field, for example $GF(4)$? What is the branch of mathematics called that deals with how to solve these types of equations?

Comment: In characteristic $p>0$ the only functions I can differentiate are rational functions in several variables. Basically reducing to the case where $\phi$ is a quotient of two polynomials. Not sure there really is *a branch of mathematics* studying those. I guess tools from algberaic geometry can be used, but I'm not sure. I guess that in differential geometry it is possible to make sense of a Laplace operator for functions $\phi:M\to\Bbb{R}/2\pi\Bbb{R}$, but I'm not sure what kind of a beast $\nabla^2\phi$ would then be? What would be its range for starters?

Comment: Oh, a second reading revealed that you actually want to use a different *domain* for $\phi$. In that case differential geometry, most notably Riemannian manifolds gives you something. Look up [Laplace-Beltrami operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Generalizations).